# Why Jenkins fails iterating for each line?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get the output of git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r somehash | grep "mypath/"

```
def var=''
var=sh(script: "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r somehash | grep 'mypath/'", returnStdout: true)

var.eachLine{
sh 'cp -rf /somepath/${it} myotherpathintheworkspace'
}
```

The problem is that jenkins var is printable, not empty.But as soon as it is embedded into sh '' segment (in a loop here, maybe the loop is the problem) it is displayed as empty like sh 'echo ${it}' is like 'echo '

Comment: "it gets stuck in the loop writing things like permission denied (which is not really true I guess)" - If you are getting permission denied errors and it isn't true that the user doesn't have permissions, that might require a bug in Git. Are you sure that whatever user id the account is running under does have permission?

Comment: have you tried `var="git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r somehash | grep 'mypath/'".execute().text`

Comment: I did but I wrote the description wrongly. Actually I am using jenkins sh().trim().toString().slice('/n') and then loop over that var. The problem is when I try to embed the iteration variable which is one given line within a sh 'echo ${myiterationvar}' which is returned as empty

Comment: @JeffScottBrown sorry I didn't write the problem well enough, the problem is that the jenkins var captured  from sh() stdout is readable in jenkins groovy, but as soon as I embed it into sh'' it is empty

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli yes that is not allowed by my sandbox I believe. I'm collecting,it via sh() jenkins function but I cannot pass it to the sh'' in a loop as I described in my recently updated description

Comment: Do you get a CPS mismatch error?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I think you will run into a CPS Mismatch issue with the `eachLine` closure.  Try the following instead

```
def var=''
var=sh(script: "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r somehash | grep 'mypath/'", returnStdout: true)

var.split('\\n').each {
    sh "echo ${it}"
}
```

That works for me.  If you have issues with this script please `println var` to verify it has line breaks

Comment: Unfortunately despite executing, the problem stays. The script prints out the Jenkins var (that's also tokenized later) but once that Jenkins Var gets embedded into sh' echo.... ' it is listed as empty

Comment: @kol23 Can you post a screenshot of your build log. Something must be weird with the specific command or the output from Git because I ran the above script with an `ls -ltr` command instead of the git command and it seemed to work.  What is your Jenkins version?

Comment: I did println Var. It does print it. But a next command sh 'echo ${Var} does not

Comment: That’s because you’re using sh’’ and not sh””. Try to copy my code exactly and only replace the ls command with your git command. Do not type it out, copy it exactly @kol23

Comment: I did also with sh "" and the result was exactly the same

Comment: Maybe you do have a groovy based copy of the file solution?

Comment: @kol23 I’m running my solution in Jenkins 2.x on an Amazon linux node. Can you copy my solution exactly then post a screenshot of your build log?